# How to hold the process for 2-3 second in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I have Boolean variable. I have timer which is based on this Boolean value. Both are in different form. Boolean is True when form is initialize. It set false on a specific condition. I want to put 2-3 second hold before it set to false.

```
//Form 1

Private void updateGrid()
{
    if(Form2.isBooleanTrue)
    {
        //Code to execurte
    }
}


//Form 2
public static isBooleanTrue = false;
Private void checkCondition()
{
    // I want to hold here. Note it should not hold the Form1 process
    isBooleanTrue = true;
}
```

Can any body suggest me how to hold the process before Boolean set false? So, timer can run for few more seconds.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(2000);` or `Thread.Sleep(3000);`

Comment: Task.Delay could be a better solution. See: http://stackoverflow.comquestions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep

Comment: @lan Will "updateGrid()" of Form1 will be running during this Sleep call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running .NET 4.5 or later with C#5 or later you can use the async/await feature.

Mark your method as `async` and (if possible, not necessary but recommended) change it's return type to [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx). Then, you can use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) to make your UI thread wait for however long you want.

The important bit is it will wait *asynchronously*, and so it won't freeze your UI, unlike if you used for example [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx), instead it will return from your method and continue execution of other code. After 3 seconds, it will run the remainder of the method as a task continuation, which will update your `isBooleanTrue` field.

Your method should now look like this:

```
private async Task checkCondition() // If you can't change the return type you can leave it as void, although it's not recommended.
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    isBooleanTrue = true;
}
```

Note that the method doesn't return anything, even though the return type is `Task`. This is a feature of the new async/await syntax, the returning `Task` will be generated automatically.

You can read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: Process of Form1 should not sleep. updateGrid() should be working during this Task.Delay(3000); call. Will it work?

Comment: Neither the process nor the thread will sleep - that's the advantage of waiting asynchronously. But don't trust my word - try it for yourself! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx), which suspends current thread for given period of time.

```
Thread.Sleep(3000); // 3 sec wait.
```

**Update**

To leave the UI responding and get updates after few seconds you can do below.

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {

    Thread.Sleep(3000); 
    // run your code on UI thread
});
```

Another option, start *asynchoronous* [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) that performs your action.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000); // wait 3 secs
    form1.Invoke(new Action(()=> 
               {
                    // your logic goes here.
               }));
});
```

Comment: Process of Form1 should not sleep. updateGrid() should be working during this Sleep call. Will it work?

Comment: yes that can be achieved, let me give you an option.